# C# Getter/Setter not working

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I am rather the Java-Guy, so handling getters/setters in C# is a little new to me.
Why is this not working?

```
public String lastmodified {
            get { return this.lastmodified; }
            set 
            { 
                long ms = Int64.Parse(value);
                var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(ms);
                date.ToLocalTime();
                this.lastmodified = date.ToString("HH_mm_yyyy");
            }
        }
```

**value** is in this cade a String which goes like 1987123019

Comment: Both of those look recursive to me. where is your member variable holding the backing store?

Answer (score 8):

Because you are assigning property itself on the last line. You should use either different casing or underscores to distinguish properties or fields.

I would recommend standard C# naming conventions. Also save the data in their native format. And also what driis said.

```
private DateTime lastModified;
public String LastModified {
        get { return lastModified.ToString("HH_mm_yyyy"); }
        set 
        { 
            long ms = Int64.Parse(value);
            var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(ms);
            date = date.ToLocalTime();
            lastModified = date;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This will get you a StackOverflowException, since you are calling the property setter recursively in the last line of `set` (and `get`, for that matter).  You need to assign the value to a field of a class, and read it from that field in the getter. Your current code simply calls into the same property accessor method infinitely, until you run out of stack space.

Common C# naming conventions suggests PascalCasing for property and method names, and camelCasing for instance variables, possibly prefixed with an underscore.

This code should work:

```
private string lastModified; // instance variable
public string LastModified 
{
    get { return this.lastModified; }
    set 
    { 
        long ms = Int64.Parse(value);
        var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(ms);
        date = date.ToLocalTime();
        this.lastModified = date.ToString("HH_mm_yyyy");
    }
}
```

Also, "Not working" is kind of broad; but I am going to guess that you will see that the `ToLocalTime` method does not get applied to the date. This is because `DateTime` in C# is immutable, so it cannot be changed after construction. You will need to assign your `date`variable to the result of `ToLocalTime()`:

```
date = date.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: The problem occurs on `long ms = Int64.Parse(value);`

Comment: If that line fails, I'd guess it is because that happens to be the call where you run out of stack space.

Comment: @Clue That can fail either when value is not really a number or number is too big for Int64

Answer (score 0):

For a property procedure, the getter should return the value of the class member variable holding the "wrapped" value. For a setter, the inbound value should be assigned to that class member variable. What you're doing makes the property self-referential.